# Mongoose model quick relations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, yii, mongoose

Is there any way to make quick relation references between models in mongoose?

For instance in Yii, it is possible to reference related models like:

```
$player->team->league->name;
```

Where as in mongoose I'm currently having to use findById:

```
Team.findById(player.team_id, function(err,team){
   if (team != null && !err){
      League.findById(team.league_id, function(err,league){
         if (league != null && !err){
            console.log(league.name);
        (..)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your schemas represent the relations between schemas (defining referenced ObjectIds in your schema) you should be able to call `populate` to automatically lookup the referenced document and exchange it for your ObjectId in the output document as following:

```
const leagueName = (await Team.findById(player.team_id)
  .populate({ 
    path: 'league_id', 
    select: 'name'
  })
).league_id.name
```